# Increase the maximum zoom level of a Google map

Tags: google-maps

How would I go about creating a Google map that allows the user to zoom beyond the default zoom levels for the map?  Would I have to create a new map type that has a greater maximum zoom?  Are there any tutorials out there that show how to do this?

Comment: wow sorry, terrible misread... :)

Comment: No problem.  Thanks anyways - it was a thorough answer albeit for the wrong question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/).  One of the things you can do is place more detailed information (an "overlay") on a map.  Note that you won't be able to get better imagery than is already there but, for example, the Google Campus itself has quite high-rez imagery.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to work with is the [GTileLayerOverlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GTileLayerOverlay). It allows you to add custom tiles to the map, providing you have higher resolution versions of the tiles. Is this your goal or were you looking for a way to get back higher resolution tiles from google? (in which case you are out of luck, except for the cases outlined [here](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2007-03-07-n12.html))