# Does Google Maps API v3 allow larger zoom values?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

If you use the satellite GMapType using this [Google-provided example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/examples/control-simple.html) in v3 of the API, the maximum zoom level has a scale of 2m / 10ft , whereas using the v2 version of [another Google-provided example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/control-maptypes.html) (had to use another one since the control-simple doesn't have the scale control) yields the maximum scale of 20m / 50ft. Is this a new "feature" of v3 ?

I have to mention that I've tested the examples in the same GLatLng regions - so my guess is that tile detail level doesn't influence it, am I mistaken ?

As mentioned [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864931/the-state-of-gmaps-v3), v3 is to be considered of very Labs-y/beta quality, so use in production should be discouraged for the time being.

I've been drawn to the subject since I have to "increase the zoom level of a GMap", [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286062/increase-the-maximum-zoom-level-of-a-google-map) seem to suggest using GTileLayer, and I'm considering [GMapCreator](http://www.casa.ucl.ac.uk/software/gmapcreator.asp), although this will involve some effort.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a larger zoom level, a scale of 2m / 10ft would be perfect, I have a map where the tiles aren't that hi-res and quite a few markers. Seeing that the area doesn't have hi-res tiles, the distance between the markers is really tiny, creating some problematic overlapping.

Or better yet, how can you create a custom Map which allows higher zoom levels, as by the Google Campus, where the 2m / 10ft scale is achieved, and *not* use your own tileserver ? I've seen an example [on a fellow Stackoverflower's GMaps sandbox](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo9) , where the tiles are manually created based on the zoom level.

I have seen [the codebase for a custom Map on mapki](http://mapki.com/wiki/Add_Your_Own_Custom_Map), but this involves having a tileserver, can't you just use Google's tiles for a specific zoom level and then swap some of them (depending on tile.x and tile.y) with custom tiles, when the zoom level is higher than 19 ?

I don't think I'm making any more sense, so I'm just going to end this big question here, I've been wondering around trying to find a solution for hours now. Hope that someone comes to my aid though !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: After investigating some more, it is indeed true - Maps v3 does allow a max zoom level of 22 (!), equating to a scale of 2m / 10ft, but only when the map type is Satellite, not Hybrid !

Comment: Fiddled around with the Automatic Tile Cuttor Photoshop plugin as well, couldn't produce the results I wanted (didn't know how exactly to scale my map so that the tiles would be perfectly arranged), using an ImageOverlay, doesn't look so pixel-y.

Comment: Have since then ported my GMaps v2 code to v3, smooth sailing. And yes, having a Satellite Map (not Hybrid !) allows a max zoom of 22, tricky placed markers (close to each other) are rendered way better. Adding an overlay + custom tiles (eventually) for "Sorry, no imagery here" did the trick in the end

Comment: Nice! You should put your comments into an Answer so that others can vote it up, and so the question can be removed from the Unanswered list.

Comment: Ok, including comments into an Answer, thanks for the tip, forgot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insights after a further investigation :

After investigating some more, it is indeed true - Maps v3 does allow a max zoom level of 22 (!), equating to a scale of 2m / 10ft, but only when the map type is Satellite, not Hybrid ! – Dr1Ku Apr 14 at 9:59

Fiddled around with the Automatic Tile Cuttor Photoshop plugin as well, couldn't produce the results I wanted (didn't know how exactly to scale my map so that the tiles would be perfectly arranged), using an ImageOverlay, doesn't look so pixel-y. – Dr1Ku Apr 14 at 10:00

Have since then ported my GMaps v2 code to v3, smooth sailing. And yes, having a Satellite Map (not Hybrid !) allows a max zoom of 22, tricky placed markers (close to each other) are rendered way better. Adding an overlay + custom tiles (eventually) for "Sorry, no imagery here" did the trick in the end – Dr1Ku May 17 at 20:17

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post an update here that v3 of the Google Maps API is now out labs and has feature parity with v2.

Also v2 of the Maps API has been deprecated, so if you're looking for better zoom features, it looks like your best option is going to be to use v3 instead of a v2.